# What is the correct way to retrieve data from a local database Android?

Tags: android, sqlite, architecture, android-room

I'm developing an app and I have a local SQLite database for keeping some user data and I am also using the Room persistence library as it is a recommended approach. I followed the tutorial and created a model, a DAO and a database itself. So in the activity I just populate my `RecyclerView` using the new thread and it is working OK.
But then I got a problem in another view where I want to change the `TextView` text to the value I got from the database. I can't do it in another thread like I did earlier because I get `CalledFromWrongThreadException` and I also can't call it from the main thread because I get `IllegalStateException`. All the tutorials I found just provided me with the info I already knew about the creation of the database and DAO, and all of them used `allowMainThreadQueries()` with a note that it shouldn't be used in production. However, more problem-related research lead me to some workarounds using `runOnUiThread()` which is not really a solution here. So I got a question:
**Is there any straightforward approach of doing this that I missed?** (Or maybe not so straightforward but rational).

Answer (score 1):

In your case access to database should looks somthing like this

```
 Thread{
        val text = dataBase.getDao().getText()
        Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post {
            textView.text = text
        }
    }.start()
```

But using `LiveData` or `RxJava2` it can be done more comfortable
Try this [LiveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata), [RxJava2](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/room-rxjava-acb0cd4f3757)

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way to use Room is with LiveData API and Lifecycle API you can check the [link](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view/) 
and I recommend you to watch other google codelabs, they helped me a lot